# Exchange associations between records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Here we have:

```
class Dice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sign_a, class_name: 'Sign'
  belongs_to :sign_b, class_name: 'Sign'
  belongs_to :sign_c, class_name: 'Sign'
  ...
  belongs_to :dice_place, polymorphic: true

  validates :sign_a, :sign_b, :sign_c, ..., :dice_place, presence: true
end

class BagDicePlace < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :dice, as: :dice_place, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Suppose we somehow got a record `bag_dice_place_1` and `bag_dice_place_2`. In each of these records association `dice` with all sub-associations are already loaded. Theoretically, it should keep within two updates in one transaction. But I don't know how to do it. How to exchange places these `dice`-s by generating a minimum number of calls to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if all are silent, I will offer his own version.

```
d1 = bag_dice_place_1.dice
d2 = bag_dice_place_2.dice

Dice.transaction do
  if d1
    d1.update(dice_place: bag_dice_place_2)
  end

  if d2
    d2.update(dice_place: bag_dice_place_1)
  end
end

bag_dice_place_1.association(:dice).target = d2
bag_dice_place_2.association(:dice).target = d1
```